Can you Fix Translated code : Python to C#
I have a Python script for detecting corners in a polygon, and I need to convert it to C# for use in Unity3D. The script utilizes algorithms such as convex hull or corner detection to identify corners in a polygonal shape. However, I want to achieve this conversion without relying on any external libraries or plugins. Could someone provide guidance or a code example on how to accomplish this efficiently in C# within the Unity environment?

import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import shapely
from shapely import speedups
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from shapely.geometry import MultiPolygon
import math
import statistics
speedups.enable()

def calculate_initial_compass_bearing(pointA, pointB):
    """
    Calculates the bearing between two points.

    The formulae used is the following:
        θ = atan2(sin(Δlong).cos(lat2),
                  cos(lat1).sin(lat2) − sin(lat1).cos(lat2).cos(Δlong))

    :Parameters:
      - `pointA: The tuple representing the latitude/longitude for the
        first point. Latitude and longitude must be in decimal degrees
      - `pointB: The tuple representing the latitude/longitude for the
        second point. Latitude and longitude must be in decimal degrees

    :Returns:
      The bearing in degrees

    :Returns Type:
      float
    """
    if (type(pointA) != tuple) or (type(pointB) != tuple):
        raise TypeError("Only tuples are supported as arguments")

    lat1 = math.radians(pointA[0])
    lat2 = math.radians(pointB[0])

    diffLong = math.radians(pointB[1] - pointA[1])

    x = math.sin(diffLong) * math.cos(lat2)
    y = math.cos(lat1) * math.sin(lat2) - (math.sin(lat1)
            * math.cos(lat2) * math.cos(diffLong))

    initial_bearing = math.atan2(x, y)

    # Now we have the initial bearing but math.atan2 return values
    # from -180° to + 180° which is not what we want for a compass bearing
    # The solution is to normalize the initial bearing as shown below
    initial_bearing = math.degrees(initial_bearing)
    compass_bearing = (initial_bearing + 360) % 360

    return compass_bearing
    


def calculate_segment_angles(polySimple, maxAngleChange = 45):
    """
    Calculates angles of all polygon segments to cardinal directions.

    :Parameters:
      - `polySimple: shapely polygon object containing simplified building.
      - `maxAngleChange: angle (0,45> degrees. Sets the maximum angle deviation
                         from the cardinal direction for the segment to be still 
                         considered to continue in the same direction as the 
                         previous segment.

    :Returns:
      - orgAngle: Segments bearing
      - corAngle: Segments angles to closest cardinal direction
      - dirAngle: Segments direction [N, E, S, W] as [0, 1, 2, 3]

    :Returns Type:
      list
    """
    # Convert limit angle to angle for subtraction
    maxAngleChange = 45 - maxAngleChange

    # Get points Lat/Lon
    simpleX = polySimple.exterior.xy[0]
    simpleY = polySimple.exterior.xy[1]

    # Calculate angle to cardinal directions for each segment of polygon
    orgAngle = [] # Original angles
    corAngle = [] # Correction angles used for rotation
    dirAngle = [] # 0,1,2,3 = N,E,S,W
    limit = [0] * 4

    for i in range(0, (len(simpleX) - 1)):
        point1 = (simpleY[i], simpleX[i])
        point2 = (simpleY[i+1], simpleX[i+1])
        angle = calculate_initial_compass_bearing(point1, point2)

        if angle > (45 + limit[1]) and angle <= (135 - limit[1]):
            orgAngle.append(angle)
            corAngle.append(angle - 90)
            dirAngle.append(1)

        elif angle > (135 + limit[2]) and angle <= (225 - limit[2]):
            orgAngle.append(angle)
            corAngle.append(angle - 180)
            dirAngle.append(2)

        elif angle > (225 + limit[3]) and angle <= (315 - limit[3]):
            orgAngle.append(angle)
            corAngle.append(angle - 270)
            dirAngle.append(3)

        elif angle > (315 + limit[0]) and angle <= 360:
            orgAngle.append(angle)
            corAngle.append(angle - 360)
            dirAngle.append(0)

        elif angle >= 0 and angle <= (45 - limit[0]):
            orgAngle.append(angle)
            corAngle.append(angle)
            dirAngle.append(0)


        limit = [0] * 4
        limit[ dirAngle[i] ] = maxAngleChange               # Set angle limit for the current direction
        limit[ (dirAngle[i] + 1) % 4 ] = -maxAngleChange    # Extend the angles for the adjacent directions
        limit[ (dirAngle[i] - 1) % 4 ] = -maxAngleChange

    return orgAngle, corAngle, dirAngle



def rotate_polygon(polySimple, angle):
    """
    Rotates polygon around its centroid for given angle.

    :Parameters:
      - `polySimple: shapely polygon object containing simplified building.
      - `angle: angle of rotation in decimal degrees.  
                Positive = counter-clockwise, Negative = clockwise 

    :Returns:
      - bSR: rotated polygon

    :Returns Type:
      shapely Polygon
    """
    # Create WGS84 referenced GeoSeries
    bS = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry':[polySimple]})
    bS.crs = "EPSG:4326"

    # Temporary reproject to Merkator and rotate by median angle
    bSR = bS.to_crs('epsg:3857')
    bSR = bSR.rotate(angle, origin='centroid', use_radians=False) 
    bSR = bSR.to_crs('epsg:4326')

    # Extract only shapely polygon object
    bSR = bSR[0]

    return bSR


def orthogonalize_polygon(polygon, maxAngleChange = 15, skewTolerance = 15):
    """
    Master function that makes all angles in polygon outer and inner rings either 90 or 180 degrees.
    Idea adapted from JOSM function orthogonalize
    1) Calculate bearing [0-360 deg] of each polygon segment
    2) From bearing determine general direction [N, E, S ,W], then calculate angle deviation from nearest cardinal direction for each segment
    3) Rotate polygon by median deviation angle to align segments with xy coord axes (cardinal directions)
    4) For vertical segments replace X coordinates of their points with mean value
       For horizontal segments replace Y coordinates of their points with mean value
    5) Rotate back

    :Parameters:
      - `polygon: shapely polygon object containing simplified building.
      - `maxAngleChange: angle (0,45> degrees. Sets the maximum angle deviation
                         from the cardinal direction for the segment to be still 
                         considered to continue in the same direction as the 
                         previous segment.
      - `skewTolerance: angle <0,45> degrees. Sets skew tolerance for segments that 
                        are at 45˚±Tolerance angle from the overal rectangular shape 
                        of the polygon. Usefull when preserving e.g. bay windows on a 
                        house.

    :Returns:
      - polyOrthog: orthogonalized shapely polygon where all angles are 90 or 180 degrees

    :Returns Type:
      shapely Polygon
    """
    # Check if polygon has inner rings that we want to orthogonalize as well
    rings = [ Polygon(polygon.exterior) ]
    for inner in list(polygon.interiors):
        rings.append(Polygon(inner))


    polyOrthog = [] 
    for polySimple in rings:

        # Get angles from cardinal directions of all segments
        orgAngle, corAngle, dirAngle = calculate_segment_angles(polySimple)

        # Calculate median angle that will be used for rotation
        if statistics.stdev(corAngle) < 30:
            medAngle = statistics.median(corAngle)
            #avAngle = statistics.mean(corAngle)
        else:
            medAngle = 45  # Account for cases when building is at ~45˚ and we can't decide if to turn clockwise or anti-clockwise

        # Rotate polygon to align its edges to cardinal directions
        polySimpleR = rotate_polygon(polySimple, medAngle)

        # Get directions of rotated polygon segments
        orgAngle, corAngle, dirAngle = calculate_segment_angles(polySimpleR, maxAngleChange)

        # Get Lat/Lon of rotated polygon points
        rotatedX = polySimpleR.exterior.xy[0].tolist()
        rotatedY = polySimpleR.exterior.xy[1].tolist()

        # Scan backwards to check if starting segment is a continuation of straight region in the same direction
        shift = 0
        for i in range(1, len(dirAngle)):
            if dirAngle[0] == dirAngle[-i]:
                shift = i
            else:
                break
        # If the first segment is part of continuing straight region then reset the index to its beginning
        if shift != 0:
            dirAngle  = dirAngle[-shift:] + dirAngle[:-shift]
            orgAngle  = orgAngle[-shift:] + orgAngle[:-shift]
            rotatedX = rotatedX[-shift-1:-1] + rotatedX[:-shift]    # First and last points are the same in closed polygons
            rotatedY = rotatedY[-shift-1:-1] + rotatedY[:-shift]

        # Fix 180 degree turns (N->S, S->N, E->W, W->E)
        # Subtract two adjacent directions and if the difference is 2, which means we have 180˚ turn (0,1,3 are OK) then use the direction of the previous segment
        dirAngleRoll = dirAngle[1:] + dirAngle[0:1]
        dirAngle = [ dirAngle[i-1] if abs(dirAngle[i]-dirAngleRoll[i])==2 else dirAngle[i] for i in range(len(dirAngle)) ]

        # Cycle through all segments
        # Adjust points coodinates by taking the average of points in segment
        dirAngle.append(dirAngle[0]) # Append dummy value
        orgAngle.append(orgAngle[0]) # Append dummy value
        segmentBuffer = [] # Buffer for determining which segments are part of one large straight line 

        for i in range(0, len(dirAngle) - 1):
            # Preserving skewed walls: Leave walls that are obviously meant to be skewed 45˚+/- tolerance˚ (e.g.angle 30-60 degrees) off main walls as untouched
            if orgAngle[i] % 90 > (45 - skewTolerance) and orgAngle[i] % 90 < (45 + skewTolerance):
                continue

            # Dealing with adjacent segments following the same direction
            segmentBuffer.append(i) 
            if dirAngle[i] == dirAngle[i + 1]: # If next segment is of same orientation, we need 180 deg angle for straight line. Keep checking.
                if orgAngle[i + 1] % 90 > (45 - skewTolerance) and orgAngle[i + 1] % 90 < (45 + skewTolerance):
                    pass
                else:
                    continue

            if dirAngle[i] in {0, 2}:   # for N,S segments avereage x coordinate
                tempX = statistics.mean( rotatedX[ segmentBuffer[0]:segmentBuffer[-1]+2 ] )
                # Update with new coordinates
                rotatedX[ segmentBuffer[0]:segmentBuffer[-1]+2 ] = [tempX] * (len(segmentBuffer) + 1)  # Segment has 2 points therefore +1
            elif dirAngle[i] in {1, 3}:  # for E,W segments avereage y coordinate 
                tempY = statistics.mean( rotatedY[ segmentBuffer[0]:segmentBuffer[-1]+2 ] )
                # Update with new coordinates
                rotatedY[ segmentBuffer[0]:segmentBuffer[-1]+2 ] = [tempY] * (len(segmentBuffer) + 1)
            
            if 0 in segmentBuffer:  # Copy change in first point to its last point so we don't lose it during Reverse shift
                rotatedX[-1] = rotatedX[0]
                rotatedY[-1] = rotatedY[0]
            
            segmentBuffer = []
        

        # Reverse shift so we get polygon with the same start/end point as before
        if shift != 0:
            rotatedX = rotatedX[shift:] + rotatedX[1:shift+1]    # First and last points are the same in closed polygons
            rotatedY = rotatedY[shift:] + rotatedY[1:shift+1]
        else:
            rotatedX[0] = rotatedX[-1]    # Copy updated coordinates to first node
            rotatedY[0] = rotatedY[-1]

        # Create polygon from new points
        polyNew = Polygon(zip(rotatedX, rotatedY))
        
        # Rotate polygon back
        polyNew = rotate_polygon(polyNew, -medAngle)
        
        # Add to list of finihed rings
        polyOrthog.append(polyNew)

    # Recreate the original object
    polyOrthog = Polygon(polyOrthog[0].exterior, [inner.exterior for inner in polyOrthog[1:]])
    return polyOrthog



## Main part

## Orthogonalize buildings
buildings = gpd.read_file('inFile.geojson')
buildings.crs = "EPSG:4326"

for i in range(0, len(buildings)):
    build = buildings.loc[i, 'geometry']

    if build.type == 'MultiPolygon': # Multipolygons
        multipolygon = []

        for poly in build:
            buildOrtho = orthogonalize_polygon(poly)
            multipolygon.append(buildOrtho)

        buildings.loc[i, 'geometry'] = gpd.GeoSeries(MultiPolygon(multipolygon)).values # Workaround for Pandas/Geopandas bug
        # buildings.loc[i, 'geometry'] = MultiPolygon(multipolygon)   # Does not work
    
    else:    # Polygons
        
        buildOrtho = orthogonalize_polygon(build)
              
        buildings.loc[i, 'geometry'] = buildOrtho


buildings.to_file('outFile.geojson', driver='GeoJSON')

The Green line is the original, Magenta is the output... I get all 4 values but one is duplicate, that why I have a triangle. Then the Orange is a boundBox with no function..

Below is my UnityC# code
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteAlways]
public class Squarer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Vector2> originalPolygonVertices;
    public float maxAngleChange = 10f;
    public float skewTolerance = 10f;


    void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Bounds boundingBox = CalculateBoundingBox(originalPolygonVertices);
        DrawBoundingBox(boundingBox);
        DrawPolygon(originalPolygonVertices, Color.green);
       DrawPolygon( OrthPolygon(originalPolygonVertices,maxAngleChange,skewTolerance),Color.magenta);

    }


    public List<Vector2> OrthPolygon(List<Vector2> polygon, float maxAngleChange = 15f, float skewTolerance = 15f)
    {
        List<Vector2> poly = new List<Vector2>();
        List<float> orgAngles;
        List<float> corAngles;
        List<int> dirAngles;
        (orgAngles, corAngles, dirAngles) = CalculateSegmentAngles(originalPolygonVertices);

        float medAngle = 0;

        if (StandardDeviation(corAngles) < 30)
        {
            medAngle = Median(corAngles);
        }
        else
        {
            medAngle = 45;
        }

        List<Vector2> polySimpleR = RotatePolygon(polygon, medAngle);
        (orgAngles, corAngles, dirAngles) = CalculateSegmentAngles(polySimpleR, maxAngleChange);

        List<float> rotatedX = new List<float>();
        List<float> rotatedY = new List<float>();

        foreach (Vector2 vertex in polySimpleR)
        {
            rotatedX.Add(vertex.x);
            rotatedY.Add(vertex.y);
        }

        int shift = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < dirAngles.Count; i++)
        {
            if (dirAngles[0] == dirAngles[dirAngles.Count - i])
            {
                shift = i;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (shift != 0)
        {
            dirAngles = dirAngles.Skip(dirAngles.Count - shift).Concat(dirAngles.Take(dirAngles.Count - shift))
                .ToList();
            orgAngles = orgAngles.Skip(orgAngles.Count - shift).Concat(orgAngles.Take(orgAngles.Count - shift))
                .ToList();
            rotatedX = rotatedX.Skip(rotatedX.Count - shift - 1).Take(rotatedX.Count - 1)
                .Concat(rotatedX.Take(rotatedX.Count - shift)).ToList();
            rotatedY = rotatedY.Skip(rotatedY.Count - shift - 1).Take(rotatedY.Count - 1)
                .Concat(rotatedY.Take(rotatedY.Count - shift)).ToList();
        }

        List<int> dirAngleRoll = dirAngles.Skip(1).Concat(dirAngles.Take(1)).ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < dirAngles.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Math.Abs(dirAngles[i] - dirAngleRoll[i]) == 2)
            {
                dirAngles[i] = dirAngles[i - 1];
            }
        }

        dirAngles.Add(dirAngles[0]); // Append dummy value
        orgAngles.Add(orgAngles[0]); // Append dummy value
        List<int> segmentBuffer = new List<int>(); // Buffer for determining which segments are part of one large straight line

        for (int i = 0; i < dirAngles.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            // Preserving skewed walls: Leave walls that are obviously meant to be skewed 45˚+/- tolerance˚ (e.g.angle 30-60 degrees) off main walls as untouched
            if (orgAngles[i] % 90 > (45 - skewTolerance) && orgAngles[i] % 90 < (45 + skewTolerance))
            {
                continue;
            }

            // Dealing with adjacent segments following the same direction
            segmentBuffer.Add(i);
            if (dirAngles[i] ==
                dirAngles
                    [i + 1]) 
            {
                if (orgAngles[i + 1] % 90 > (45 - skewTolerance) && orgAngles[i + 1] % 90 < (45 + skewTolerance))
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }

            if (dirAngles[i] == 0 || dirAngles[i] == 2) // for N,S segments average x coordinate
            {
                float tempX = rotatedX.GetRange(segmentBuffer[0], segmentBuffer.Count).Average();
                // Update with new coordinates
                for (int j = segmentBuffer[0]; j <= segmentBuffer[segmentBuffer.Count - 1]; j++)
                {
                    rotatedX[j] = tempX;
                }
            }
            else if (dirAngles[i] == 1 || dirAngles[i] == 3) // for E,W segments average y coordinate
            {
                float tempY = rotatedY.GetRange(segmentBuffer[0], segmentBuffer.Count).Average();
                // Update with new coordinates
                for (int j = segmentBuffer[0]; j <= segmentBuffer[segmentBuffer.Count - 1]; j++)
                {
                    rotatedY[j] = tempY;
                }
            }

            if (segmentBuffer.Contains(0)) 
            {
                rotatedX[rotatedX.Count - 1] = rotatedX[0];
                rotatedY[rotatedY.Count - 1] = rotatedY[0];
            }

            segmentBuffer.Clear();
        }

if (shift != 0)
        {
            rotatedX = rotatedX.Skip(shift).Concat(rotatedX.Take(shift + 1)).ToList();
            rotatedY = rotatedY.Skip(shift).Concat(rotatedY.Take(shift + 1)).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            rotatedX[0] = rotatedX[rotatedX.Count - 1]; // Copy updated coordinates to first node
            rotatedY[0] = rotatedY[rotatedY.Count - 1];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < rotatedX.Count; i++)
        {
            poly.Add(new Vector2(rotatedX[i], rotatedY[i]));
        }

        return RotatePolygon(poly,- medAngle);
    }
  
}


Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
